# CKSubscription not working if record owner is self

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

If I create a `CKRecord` using `CKDatabase.saveRecord`, no `CKSubscription` notification is triggered when that record is inserted by myself. Apparently I only get notifications if somebody else inserted a record, but I'd like to uniformly receive notifications, regardless if the record was created by me or somebody else.

Also I didn't find a mention about this behavior in the docs.

I tried for ages to receive notifications after creating the record on the same device, but it only finally worked if i created an artificial record in the dashboard.

Is there a flag to change this behavior?

Comment: No, you only receive subscription notifications for records created or modified off the device. If you insert/change a record on your device you need to handle this directly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. But where is this documented?

Comment: See the paragraph under the heading "Test Subscriptions" - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only receive subscription notifications for records created, deleted or modified off the device. If you insert/change/delete a record on your device you need to handle this directly.

From the *[Cloud Kit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH8-SW1)* guide (emphasis added)

> ## Test Subscriptions
>
> You can initially test subscriptions by running your app through Xcode and using CloudKit Dashboard to create, modify, or delete records, as described in Add, Modify, and Delete Records. Then fully test subscriptions by running your app on multiple devices. Use one device to make changes and another device to receive the subscription notifications. **You use multiple devices because a notification isn’t sent to the same device that originated the notification**